# Can I change the Contents of the website after it gets deployed on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment, content-management-system

I have a website in asp.net which contains a User Input form page where user can enter various details like Name, Id, Contact No, Address etc. Now as per my requirement I have to make this webpage generic such that in future if the Client wants to change the Name with Employee Name, Id to wwid, Contact No to Mobile No etc. it should be changed.
Now I have two points in my mind to try this.

1. First one will be to make the Content Management system (CMS) and store, retrieve from there.
2. Now my doubt and question. Can I replace the Contents of the webpage after deployment on Button Click to avoid storing and retrieving from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all your human-readable strings in a standard .resx file. You can develop your C# code and ASPX/ASCX controls to read strings from there. The client can edit the .resx file if he wants to. Just make sure that if you deploy a new version, you don't overwrite his changes. Guides: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

Comment: @Can user update the .resx file by button click from the aspx page?

Comment: Theoretically, yes, if the web application is allowed to write its own files, but this is not common practice. A resx is a very simple XML file, you can edit that with any kind of XML API in .NET. A database would be a better alternative if you want to create an admin page for your language resources.

Comment: Sir will reading strings from database will slow down the rendering of the webpage?

Comment: You should read all strings from the database once and cache them, for example in HttpRuntime.Cache or HttpApplicationState.

Comment: Sir if i retrieve all the strings from the database once and make a cache of them will make my webpage rendering fast?

Comment: Yes, you won't notice any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by storing strings which should be changed in future in database (no matter which) and when loading page read them.

Second alternative is in fejesjoco post.

Comment: Sir will reading strings from database will slow down the rendering of the webpage?

Comment: It depend on amount of loaded data, performance of database engine etc. but in this context I don't think that this approach could be performance bottleneck of your web. I suggest try load data for each page when it's rendering. I don't see any other standard way of achieving your target, even fejesjoco post seems potentially more problematic for me because database manipulation seems much more handy and comfortable for user than file editing and it's independent on deploying of new version.

Answer (score 1):

You can render your pages and use the client-side (Javascript/jquery) to modify the structure of the page. Maybe you can use ajax posts to wait only for parts of the page instead of waiting for the whole page to appear, depends on your situation.

Comment: while using ajax post for this situation which call be best suited is it Asynchronous or Synchronous?

Comment: Try them out and you will see the difference, watch a few tutorials, they should help you.